# MaterailApp widget not easing in gracefully

Tags: flutter

The demo app which is created using flutter create when launched on the device has the screen appear with jank and does not ease in when built using the flutter version now.

Earlier, when built using the Flutter version available on October, 2019, the app worked fine and the screen transitioned gracefully with no jank.

The Flutter version I use now:

> Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.7 • channel stable •
>   https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 9f5ff2306b
>   (3 months ago) • 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800 Engine • revision
>   a67792536c Tools • Dart 2.7.0

Please note : Both the builds(previous and current) are debug builds and not release builds.
Also, the widget code remains the same as well with no difference.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: show your code and may be screenshots with artefacts

Comment: It is the basic code generated by flutter first when creating an app(the one with counter saying no. of taps). I have literally done no modifications.